# Is the IE 7 in Windows Media Center a full featured IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, mediacenter

I'm getting reports from my website of weird Javascript errors in a piece of code that normally works well, all with the following user agent:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)

Should I assumed that the IE7 in Windows Media Center is a full-blown IE and really investigate this? (in case it may also happen for other users of IE 7)

Or can I assume this is some kind of Windows Media Center quirk and brush it off? (yes, I am willing to lose this percentage of users in exchange for not having to actually get a Media Center just to test IE7 in it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My user agent on IE8 on Windows Vista SP2 64-bit:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; Zune 3.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)

The Media Center PC 5.0 just means that Media Center is installed on the system (its Windows Vista Home Premium or Windows Vista Ultimate pretty much).

Here's the break down of the user agent you provided:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)

Mozilla/4.0 -- Netscape 4.0
compatible - Compatible with whatever we just claimed to be, but not actually
MSIE 7.0 - Internet Explorer 7.0
Windows NT 6.0 - Windows Vista
WOW64 - 32-bit IE on a 64-bit Windows
Trident/4.0 - I'm really Internet Explorer 8 trying to be Internet Explorer 7 --> this might be the source of your problems
GTB6 - Google Toolbar 6 is installed
SLCC1 -  Secure Licensing Commerce Client is available (for Windows Anytime Upgrade detection)
.NET CLR 2.0.50727 - .NET Framework 2 is installed
Media Center PC 5.0 - Windows Media Center 5 (the version in Windows Vista) is installed
.NET CLR 3.0.30618 - .NET Framework 3 is installed

Comment: Thank you very much! Guess i'll have to look at those errors after all... The IE8 posing as IE7 bit was extremely helpful, I didn't know to read that part! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure it's an actual Media Center PC. It seem like some version of IE7.

EDIT: The WOW64 is the 32 compatability layer on a 64bit system - that might ring a bell.

Anyway I found it at:
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html, maybe that helps a little.

Comment: But then what does the "Media Center PC 5.0" in there mean?

Comment: Just a capability of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a list of plugins installed along with the browser?

I shouldn't care too much for integrated browsers, unless your site is in the same topic.

Comment: I don't really care about users in Media Center, I just want to make sure this can't happen to "real" IE7 users too...